# Selenium Testing in Android Devices without USB connection

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, test-automation-framework, unit-tests, functional

How can I do my selenium testing by opening the browser in android device from my PC, without connecting through USB?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution at http://stuffandtech.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-quick-tip-adb-over-wifi.html. It worked for me.

Steps from article:

1. Connect with USB debugging and do `adb tcpip 5555` result is:

> restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

2. Now do `adb connect <you'r devices IP adress>` result is:

> connected to (you'r devices IP adress)

You should now be able to debug against you'r device as usual as long as it is connected to the same WiFi as you'r computer. A simple test: `adb devices` Should give the output:

> List of devices attached: you'r devices IP adress device

Comment: Could you please edit your post to summarize the article? That way if the author deletes it or readers are at work and BlogSpot is blocked (my situation), they have the essential information.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps mentioned below:

1. `adb tcpip 5555`
   This should give the output:
   restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
2. Now knowing the IP of your Android device (Settings->About->Status) type the following into the terminal:
   `adb connect <your device's IP address>`
   You should now get the output:
   `connected to &lt;your device's IP address`
3. You should now be able to debug on your device as usual as long as it is connected to the same WiFi as your computer. A simple test:
   `adb devices` should give the output:

   `List of devices attached: &lt;your device's IP address device`

Now you can debug on your mobile wireless with one basic condition that both laptop and mobile should be connected to the same WiFi network.